# Opening various csv files, processing and then saving them through multiprocessing?

Tags: python

I am new to multiprocessing. Here I am just trying opening multiple csv files and then again saving them through multiprocessing.

```
def opening_file(x):
    print(x)
    url = 'D:\\Tanmay\\Market\\Data\\Processed GFDL_options\\Bank Nifty\\Intraday\\'
    d = pd.read_csv(url+x)
    d.to_csv('D:\\Tanmay\\trial\\'+x)

all_files = os.listdir('D:\\Tanmay\\Market\\Data\\Processed GFDL_options\\Bank Nifty\\Intraday\\')
processes = []
for i in all_files:
    
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=opening_file(i),args=(i,))
    pid = os.getpid()
    print(pid)
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
    
    
for y in processes:
    y.join()
```

Issue here is that I am only getting one process id, which means that only 1 process is running. Kindly assist

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a function to `multiprocessing.Process`, and not its result:

```py
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=opening_file, args=(i,))
```

Comment: When I do it, it seems the function opening_file is not run. I.e no csv is being saved

Comment: Does your `for i in all_files` loop run?

Comment: Yes, this i is running